# Differentiable with discontinuous partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for examples of functions defined on $\mathbb R^n$ which are differentiable but whose partial derivatives are not continuous. In the reals I guess the simplest example is $x^2 \sin{1/x}$ but the generalisation of this to higher dimensions is too messy for me (e.g. $(x^2+y^2)\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}$) and I was wondering if there are nicer examples (particularly in $\mathbb R^2$)

Comment: Why do you think $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
(x^2+y^2)\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},&(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
0,&(x,y)=(0,0).
\end{cases}$$ is not nice? Differentiability is clear and the partial derivatives reduce to the $1$-dimensional case.

Comment: And with a polar coordinate change, the expression is quite similar.

Comment: It isn't that bad but I thought there would be something nicer. Maybe there isn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a one-dimensional example, it automatically produces higher dimensional ones. Let 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2\sin\frac1x, & x\ne 0, \\ 0, & x=0,\end{cases}$$
and define 
$$
F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)=f(x_1).$$
If you want *all* partial derivatives to be discontinuous, then define
$$
F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)=f(x_1)+ f(x_2)+ \ldots+f(x_n).$$

Comment: I never thought of that as simple as it sounds. Thank you

Comment: @Reltih88: You are welcome. Glad it helped.